# If the derivative of distribution is square integrable, then so is the distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $T \in \mathcal{D}'(0,1)$ be such that $\frac{dT}{dx} \in L^2(0,1)$. Show that $T \in L^2(0,1)$.

My attempt:

Let $\frac{dT}{dx} =f$ and $g=\int_{0}^{x} f(x) dx$.
Then $g'=f=\frac{dT}{dx}$. Hence, $T-g=c$.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: What's missing is to show that $g \in L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer,  $g$ is absolutely continuous hence continuous on $(0,1)$, hence square integrable?

Comment: Pretty much, but you need to show that $g$ doesn't grow too fast near $1$. That follows immediately from $f \in L^2(0,1) \subset L^1(0,1)$ for example.

Comment: And the lower limit of the integral ought to be $0$, $f$ isn't defined outside $(0,1)$.

Comment: I fixed that. Thanks.